# Spark Streaming: Rdd.Count() not returning a valid number

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In my application I have two JavaDStreams which contain some data.  I am attempting to count the number of rows in each JavaDStream however the result I am receiving in the log isn't a number but rather a completely different object that its outputting to the log.  What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
//map score result set to tweets
JavaDStream<Tuple5<Long, String, Float, Float, String>> result =
        scoredTweets.map(new ScoreTweetsFunction());

//get extra elements
JavaDStream<Tuple7<Long, String, String, String, String, String, String>> extra_elements =
        json.map(new GetExtraElements());

//join elements with score result
System.out.println("Number of Rows in extra elements RDD: " + extra_elements.count());
System.out.println("Number of Rows in result RDD: " + result.count());
```

Output from Log:

```
Number of Rows in extra elements RDD: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream@73358a55
Number of Rows in result RDD: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream@242aa3b2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DStream` is not a `RDD` but a continuous and potentially infinite sequence of RDDs. Because of that it cannot be counted and it is not how `count` method is intended to work.

Instead it transforms existing stream into another stream where each RDD

> *has a single element generated by counting each RDD of this DStream*

If you want to perform some action on individual RDDs you should use `foreachRDD`.